# How to click a JS link with Selenium in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium

I am new to Selenium and trying to build a project with it. I need to learn how to click a JS link. There are many items listed by pages. Pagination is done by JS, unfortunately. here is an example...

```
<ul class="pagination museo-700">
    <li class="first hidden disabled">
        <a href="#">First</a>
    </li>
    <li class="prev disabled">
        <a class="arrow" href="#">
            <img src="/areas/site/Content/images/page/pagination-prev-arrow.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page active">
        <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page">
        <a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <a class="arrow" href="#">
            <img src="/areas/site/Content/images/page/pagination-next-arrow.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="last hidden">
        <a href="#">Last</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to click pages 1., 2., 3. ,4. and 5. pages above. Please give me a clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first locate the pager with a CSS selector and then each link by link text:

```c#
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul.pagination"))
      .FindElement(By.LinkText("1")).Click();
```

You could also use an XPath:

```c#
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='#'][text()='1']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 2):

code not tested but I feel like they should work

```
.page > a:contains("1")
.page > a:contains("2")
.page > a:contains("3")
.page > a:contains("4")
.page > a:contains("5")
```

or

```
//li[contains(@class, 'page')]/a[text()='1']
```